# Python socket programming: "Address already in use" after exception

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have a little server running on my Raspberry Pi which listens at a specific port. However, whenever an exception occurs during a connection and the connection is terminated, it seems that the assignment to the port is not "unbound".

This is an example code:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 5005))
    s.listen(1)
    with s.accept()[0] as c:
        raise Exception() # Act as if anything goes wrong
```

When I run it for the first time and do a `telnet localhost 5005` on another terminal, the connection is made and the server raises the Exception as expected.
However, when I try to run it for a second time, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testsocketexception.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.bind(('', 5005))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

How can I make sure that the socket is unbound even if an exception is raised on the server?
(By the way, this doesn't seem to happen in Windows.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option before binding the socket.

> the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in
>   `TIME_WAIT` state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire.
>
> [from `socket` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)

---

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('', 5005))
    ...
```

NOTE: You will get an error even if you apply this, if there's `TIME_WAIT` socket is remained from the previous run (without the `SO_REUSEADDR` option).